# Sorting and pagination with many search fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, pagination

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and tried to implement sorting, filtering and pagination in my MVC application. Generally it's OK - it works, but I don't like code which is the result of this - it's terrible, problematic and complicating.

Here is my model:

```
public class ProductOccurence
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductOccurenceId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductBuyDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsPromotional { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
}
```

and ProductSearchModel class (ViewModel only for fields to search):

```
public class ProductOccurenceSearchModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public decimal? PriceFrom { get; set; }
    public decimal? PriceTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BuyDateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BuyDateTo { get; set; }
    public bool? IsPromotional { get; set; }
}
```

also declaration of controller function:

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, ProductOccurenceSearchModel searchModel, string currentFilterDescription, string currentFilterShopName, decimal? currentFilterPriceFrom, decimal? currentFilterPriceTo, DateTime? currentFilterBuyDateFrom, DateTime? currentFilterBuyDateTo, bool? currentFilterIsPromotional, int? page)
```

as you can see, there is a lot of variables - also I need separate ViewBag for each field. In every place I need to refer to each variable, what is inelegant, illegible - and makes unnecessary redundant code.

In my view it looks like this:

Link for sorting column:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ID", "Index", new
                    {
                        sortOrder = ViewBag.IDSortParm,
                        currentFilterDescription = ViewBag.CurrentFilterDescription,
                        currentFilterShopName = ViewBag.CurrentFilterShopName,
                        currentFilterPriceFrom = ViewBag.CurrentFilterPriceFrom,
                        currentFilterPriceTo = ViewBag.CurrentFilterPriceTo,
                        currentFilterBuyDateFrom = ViewBag.CurrentFilterBuyDateFrom,
                        currentFilterBuyDateTo = ViewBag.CurrentFilterBuyDateTo,
                        currentFilterIsPromotional = ViewBag.CurrentFilterIsPromotional
                    })
```

and PagedList helper:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.ProductOccurences, page => Url.Action("Index", new
   {
       page,
       sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
       currentFilterDescription = ViewBag.CurrentFilterDescription,
       currentFilterShopName = ViewBag.CurrentFilterShopName,
       currentFilterPriceFrom = ViewBag.CurrentFilterPriceFrom,
       currentFilterPriceTo = ViewBag.CurrentFilterPriceTo,
       currentFilterBuyDateFrom = ViewBag.CurrentFilterBuyDateFrom,
       currentFilterBuyDateTo = ViewBag.CurrentFilterBuyDateTo,
       currentFilterIsPromotional = ViewBag.CurrentFilterIsPromotional
   }))
```

This is needed to store the results while paging and sorting (parameters are transfered by URL).
I was looking for solutions, I read the tutorials, but never found a good solution for many search fields (only for one or two).
How can I make it simple and clean? For example through the transfer of all the values in one object or something like this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your controller, what's the difference between the properties of `ProductOccurenceSearchModel` and the parameters named `currentDescription`, etc.? The other set appears redundant, as they both appear to contain the search input.

Comment: I followed tutorial linked above and there are two arguments in controller declaration for one search field - string currentFilter, string searchString. So I made it according to this method. ProductSearchModel variable allowed me to reduce the amount of unnecessary arguments in the controller, but I can't use SearchModel also for view... This doesn't work with ViewBag and Url.Action.

Comment: ProductOccurenceSearchModel searchModel variable is used for handling user input (when something is changed and user presses "Search" button, then paging is reseted to 1). Other seven parameters are used to remember values during sorting and paging, transfered by URL. Because it seems to me that there is no redundant code.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *but I can't use SearchModel also for view... This doesn't work with ViewBag and Url.Action.* In my opinion, it is ideal to use a model than the ViewBag for what you are doing. So I would include your `currentXXX` parameters in your `ProductSearchModel`.

Comment: Of course I tried this approach. But the problem is that my URL's don't work as they should. For example, then during my pagination my URL is like Product?page=1&currentFilter=ViewModels.ProductSearchModel - and doesn't work, filtering is broken.  I think current filter variables should be simple type, like String.
In my view I have: currentFilter = Model.CurrentFilter (Model.CurrentFilter is type of ProductSearchModel)

Comment: You still have to provide your `Html.ActionLink` filter with a RouteValueDictionary whose values are from your Model properties.

Comment: Other than that, your `Html.ActionLink` is fine. Alternatives are you could change your Controller method to accept a delimited string or a JSON string (which I think is ugly), or change your Controller method to respond to a POST (but you can't use Html.ActionLink for that).